# Bootstrap tooltip viewport and placement

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm trying to place the Bootstrap tooltip on top of element if it fits in some wrapper area. If it is does not fit then it should automatically reposition itself(on bottom for example).

Viewport and placement should handle this cases but I cannot make them work.
I tried to use viewport and placement in different ways but it fails.

```
$('#tooltip1').tooltip(
{
    placement:'top auto',
    viewport: '.viewport'
});
```

I want `'#tooltip1'` be placed on top because it fits in viewport.
http://jsfiddle.net/yzhow8vt/2/

Comment: you didn't say what you expect #tooltip2 to do.

Comment: `placement:'auto top'` seems to do the right thing for #tooltip1

Comment: @cvrebert  , updated my question and fiddle. #tooltip1 fit viewport but displayed on bottom. Looks like viewport not made any effect

Comment: "#tooltip1 fit viewport but displayed on bottom" No, it's on top in your fiddle.

Comment: @cvrebert sorry. forget to update fiddler link